CSS resizing issue
im only practicing html and css my problem is why my border have the same height with the elements when in full size but when i minimize my browser the border height of the second border changes it's height on its own?


body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  background-color: azure;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px;
  min-height: 160px;
}
<div class="box">ey
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta sed harum veniam, soluta doloremque quibusdam aspernatur unde dolorem sequi consequatur culpa exercitationem qui magnam voluptates. Corrupti nemo commodi pariatur delectus.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">ayo
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus quis voluptas hic vero perferendis dicta eaque corporis, sapiente numquam veniam, animi sit nostrum ex temporibus a quae nulla ullam facilis!</p>
</div>




The elements will be as tall as necessary to hold the contents, so if one has more content it will be taller.

Frankly, float is an outdated layout method. I suggest you look into flexbox or CSS-Grid

The issue is that the two texts have different lengths, and since you haven’t set a fixed height, the container will automatically adjust its size as the text doesn't fit. Try using max-height to prevent the container from growing beyond a certain height.

I'll add max height or ill change the min height to max height?
